# Does binding energy in molecules change under physically pressure?

Tags: energy, pressure, physical-chemistry, molecules

Does physically pressure change the binding energy between the atoms in a molecule or is it always the same? I did not find anything about this in the internet? Maybe I was searching the wrong way.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: It may change in a "condensed" matter under pressure, but not in gases - due to long inter-molecular distance in gases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, binding energies of Molecules do depend on the pressure. In a simplified classical view, a molecule can be represented by atoms connected with springs with a potential that looks something like the Morse potential (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_potential)
[image]

With the bond dissociation (bond-breaking) energy energy $D_0$ at equilibrium distance $r_e$.
If you put your liquid or solid under pressure (pressure does not really make sense for a single molecule), you will slightly decrease the length of some (or all) bonds in your molecules, like compressing the spring. Thus your system will be located further up the potential hill at $r<r_e$. From there you need less energy to break the bonds.

As Vladimir Kalitvianski has pointed out, that does not really play a role in a gas. Before you significantly decrease your bond distances due to pressure, you will have turned your substance into a solid or liquid.